# AngularJS 1.6: Label inside Component not updating when watch triggers

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

I have a $watch in my component which is keeping an eye on a factory for changes.

This part works and I can see the $watch noticing and responding.

My problem is that I need to cause the template to re-render with the new
label. before I moved to a $watch I was able to use $apply to nudge the page 
into reloading but that doesn't seem to work now.

I can also plug in an alert and see that the updated information is definitely hitting the component.

`

```
mapApp.component("vesselInfo", {
    template : '<div class="vessel-info" >
                  <div ng-bind="viCtrl.title"></div>
                </div>',
     bindings: {   
     },
     controller: VesselInfoController,
     controllerAs: 'viCtrl'
});

function VesselInfoController($scope, $element, $attrs, $http, SelectedVessel) {

    this.title = 'No Vessel Selected';

    // bind the controller property to the service collection
      this.selectedVessel = SelectedVessel.getSelectedVessel();

      // watch the collection for changes
      $scope.$watch(watchSource, function(current, previous){
        this.selectedVessel = current;
        if(current) {
            this.title = 'Name : ' + current.name;
        }
        else {
            this.title = 'No Vessel Selected';
        }           
      });

      function watchSource(){
        return SelectedVessel.getSelectedVessel();
      } 
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the following code

```
$scope.$watch(watchSource, function(current, previous) {
    // Your watch code here
}, true);
```

At the end of your $watch invocation, you can pass a third argument which handles objectEquality (see docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch))
If you pass `true` here it will use `angular.equals` method which should handle checking your collection for differences more thoroughly.

Comment: I had a try and read through the link info. This unfortunately didn't help and from reading it I think all it does is make the comparison more efficient for complex objects? which is probably a good idea for my code but the comparison itself worked fine before.

Comment: Have you checked that your `watchSource()` function is being invoked repeatedly?

Comment: I just went and had a look at that specifically and it is being called twice for each watch trigger, the first when the update happens and then again after the $watch completes. The data stays consistent across the two though so its not going to null the second time or anything.

Comment: Could you try and adjust your `$scope.$watch` to `$scope.$watch(this.selectedVessel, ...`

Comment: changing it to either $scope.$watch(SelectedVessel.getSelectedVessel() or $scope.$watch(this.selectedVessel break it and the watch doesn't trigger at all anymore. I am pretty sure the watch is firing at it should be anyhow and pulling in the updated information and getting it into the component. The only thing that seems to not be happening is for the ng-bind to update like it should do in the html.